# MDT 2010 x64 server and x86 clients

Tags: mdt-2010

I have successfully captured an x64 Win 7 image for deployment, and am trying to do the same for x86 architectures.  I understand that you need to create the catalog on an x86 machine, I was wondering if I could get some guidance on how to do such a task.

Answer (score 2):

You generate the catalogs by installing WAIK on a 32bit system and running the Windows System Image Manager on that image.